# I have to create a chat application using twilio IP Messaging in android.

Tags: android, ip, twilio, messaging

I have to create a chat application using twilio IP Messaging in android. Using twilio my application is able to chat in group using public channels. I want to connect two user and they chat..Anyone has idea then please share thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a private channel, add those two users there. Channel will be visible only to participants.

Comment: thank u for answering..but i want that clicking on user name and start chating.what would be process..any idea

Comment: I acheive my goal using different api..thanks but anyone have idea how to do this must reply